# Apache HttpClient multiple redirect issue

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

I am facing one issue where there is a URL that has multiple redirects. My code working fine on my local window 10 with JDK (1.8.0_211) whereas the same code doesn't work on AMAZON Linux with open JDK (1.8.0_212) and getting 403 error.
Apache HTTP client version : 4.5.10

See my code snippet

```
public static void test() throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
        NamingException, UnsupportedOperationException, IOException {

    System.out.println("Start");
    LaxRedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new LaxRedirectStrategy();
    final RequestConfig config;
    final CloseableHttpClient client;
    PoolConnectionManager connectionManager = new PoolConnectionManager();
    connectionManager.init();

    config = RequestConfig.custom().setRelativeRedirectsAllowed(true).setCircularRedirectsAllowed(true).setConnectionRequestTimeout(30000)
            .setSocketTimeout(60000).build();
    client = HttpClients.custom().setConnectionManager(connectionManager.getConnectionManager())
            .setRedirectStrategy(redirectStrategy).setSSLHostnameVerifier(NoopHostnameVerifier.INSTANCE).setDefaultRequestConfig(config).setUserAgent(USER_AGENT).build();

    getData(URL, client);
    System.out.println("End");
}

public static String getData(final String url, final CloseableHttpClient client)
        throws UnsupportedOperationException, IOException {
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(url);

    httpget.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
    httpget.setHeader("Connection", "keep-alive");
    httpget.setHeader("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
    httpget.setHeader("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
    CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(httpget);
    try {
        int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
        if (status == 200)
            System.out.println("Success");
        else
            System.out.println("Error")
        // Get hold of the response entity
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        // If the response does not enclose an entity, there is no need
        // to bother about connection release
        if (entity != null) {
            InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
            String text = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(instream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)).lines()
                    .collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
            //System.out.println(text);
            return text;
        }

    } finally {
        response.close();
        httpget.releaseConnection();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Multiple redirects contain cookies too. which passes in subsequent requests I have checked it with the browser. Is there any possibility that due to machine or JDK cookies not passed or other issues occurs?

My URL chain looks like 307(url 1) >> 301 (url 2) >> 301 (url 3) >> 200 (url 4) for windows box but in case of Linux Url chain looks like 307 >> 301 >> 302 >> error.

- url 1 : http://www.example.com/TESTCheck.php
- url 2 : https://www.example.com/TESTCheck.php (contains cookies in response)
- url 3 : https://www.example.com/testcheck.php (contains cookies in response)
- url 4 : https://www.example.com/date?t=q1 (contains cookies in response)

Something wrong happen which url 3 in Linux machine with open JDK (1.8.0_212)

Thank you

Comment: Please provide full logs of both sessions (Windows and Linux) http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/logging.html

Comment: I have checked on Linux with OpenJDK version 1.8.0_282. It working fine. is there any bug in OpenJDK 1.8.0_212 like URL case sensitive issue see URL 2 and URL 3. both having same URL  with some character in upper case.